# MultiValueDictKeyError at , when rendering multiple formsets with prefixes

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Hello folks Im back with a new riddle .
Im trying to render a form and 2 formsets and to do so I use prefixes.
But I dont seem to understand how to use prefixes .
The result is that when I try to add more forms to the formsets with an add button i get the error mentioned above.If you can provide me with a solution or even show me some tips i would be glad .

Here is my views.py(i dont include the imports):

```
def get_researchnew(request):
    change_crit = '0'
    change_alt = '0'
    CriterionFormSet = formset_factory(CreateCriterionForm,extra=1,can_delete=True)
    AlternativeFormset = formset_factory(CreateAlternativeForm,extra=1,can_delete=True)
    if request.method == 'POST':        
        if 'add_criterion' in request.POST:
                post_data = request.POST.copy() 
                post_data['criterion_form-TOTAL_FORMS'] = int(post_data['criterion_form-TOTAL_FORMS']) + 1 
                research_form = CreateResearchForm(post_data,prefix='research_form')
                criterion_formset = CriterionFormSet(post_data, request.FILES,prefix='criterion_form')
                alternative_formset = AlternativeFormset(post_data,request.FILES,prefix='alternative_form')
                change_crit ='1'
        elif 'add_alternative' in request.POST:
                post_data = request.POST.copy()
                post_data['alternative_form-TOTAL_FORMS'] = int(post_data['alternative_form-TOTAL_FORMS']) + 1
                research_form = CreateResearchForm(post_data,prefix='research_form')
                criterion_formset = CriterionFormSet(post_data, request.FILES,prefix='criterion_form')
                alternative_formset = AlternativeFormset(post_data,request.FILES,prefix='alternative_form')
                change_alt = '1'
        elif 'submit' in request.POST:
            research_form = CreateResearchForm(request.POST,prefix='research_form')
            criterion_formset = CriterionFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES,prefix='criterion_form')
            alternative_formset = AlternativeFormset(request.POST,request.FILES,prefix='alternative_form')
            if research_form.is_valid() and criterion_formset.is_valid() and alternative_formset.is_valid():
                research_form.save()
                research_instance = research.objects.last()
                for form in criterion_formset:
                    if form.is_valid():
                        instance = form.save(commit=False)
                        instance.criterion_research = research_instance
                        instance.save()
                for form in alternative_formset:
                        instance = form.save(commit=False)
                        instance.alternative_research = research_instance
                        instance.ranking = '1'
                        instance.save()
                return HttpResponse('Research successfully added to database.')
    else:
        research_form = CreateResearchForm(prefix='research_form')
        criterion_formset = CriterionFormSet(prefix='criterion_forms')
        alternative_formset = AlternativeFormset(prefix='alternative_form')
    return render(request,'CreateResearchnew.html',{
                                                'research_form':research_form,
                                                'criterion_formset':criterion_formset,
                                                'alternative_formset':alternative_formset,
                                                'change_crit':change_crit,
                                                'change_alt':change_alt,
                                                })
```

CreateResearchnew.html:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
    {% for field in research_form %}
        <th>
            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ field.label_tag }} 
            <br>
            {{ field }}
        </th>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
    {{ criterion_formset.management_form }}
    <table>
    {% for criterion_form in criterion_formset %}
        <tr>
        {% for field in criterion_form %}
        <th>
            {% if change_crit != '1' %}
                {{ field.errors }}
            {% endif %}
            {{ field.label_tag }} 
            <br>
            {{ field }}
        </th>
        {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
    <input title='Add a new Criterion' type='submit' name='add_criterion' value='Add' />
    {{ alternative_formset.management_form }}
    <table>
    {% for alternative_form in alternative_formset %}
        <tr>
        {% for field in alternative_form %}
        <th>
            {% if change_alt != '1' %}
                {{ field.errors }}
            {% endif %}
            {{ field.label_tag }} 
            <br>
            {{ field }}
        </th>
        {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
    <input title='Add a new Alternative' type='submit' name='add_alternative' value='Add' />
    <input title='Submit' type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' /> 
</form>
```

Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.2:8888/utastar/get_research

Django Version: 1.10.5
Python Version: 2.7.13
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'utastar']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\Flokos\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\Flokos\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\Flokos\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Flokos\Documents\mysite\utastar\views.py" in get_researchnew
  87.               post_data['criterion_form-TOTAL_FORMS'] = int(post_data['criterion_form-TOTAL_FORMS']) + 1 

File "C:\Users\Flokos\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py" in __getitem__
  85.             raise MultiValueDictKeyError(repr(key))

Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError at /utastar/get_research
Exception Value: "'criterion_form-TOTAL_FORMS'"
```

Comment: That's a wall of code. Please give a [minimal, complete and verifiable exampe](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That includes a full traceback of your error.

Comment: Why are you attempting to modify the post data? Why do you think you need to set the total forms babies manually?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman Im trying to modify the post data so I can include the new "total form babies" and render the page with one more form for the specific formset .